# YCM does not find my headers?

Tags: python, c, vim, header-files, vim-plugin

I have the following folder structure:

```
.
├── include
│   └── ctset
│       ├── hashtable.h
│       └── set.h
└── src
    └── hashtable
        └── hashtable.c
```

And in `hashtable.c` the include `#include "ctset/hashtable.h"`,
but YCM keeps telling me that it doesn't know the types I defined in the header and use in the source.

My `.ycm_extra_conf.py` is almost the default one with some adjustments:

```
# This file is NOT licensed under the GPLv3, which is the license for the rest
# of YouCompleteMe.
#
# Here's the license text for this file:
#
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
#
# Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
# distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
# binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
# means.
#
# In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors
# of this software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the
# software to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit
# of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and
# successors. We intend this dedication to be an overt act of
# relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this
# software under copyright law.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
# OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
# ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
# OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
# For more information, please refer to <http://unlicense.org/>

import os
import ycm_core

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-DNDEBUG',

# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don't want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c++11'.
'-std=c99',

# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x', 'c',

'-I', '.',

'-I', './src/',

'-I', './include/',

'-I', './ClangCompleter',

'-isystem', '../llvm/include',

'-isystem', '../llvm/tools/clang/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/local/include',

]

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
#
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None

SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm' ]

def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return list( flags )
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

    if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def IsHeaderFile( filename ):
  extension = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 1 ]
  return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh' ]


def GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename ):
    # The compilation_commands.json file generated by CMake does not have entries
    # for header files. So we do our best by asking the db for flags for a
    # corresponding source file, if any. If one exists, the flags for that file
    # should be good enough.
    if IsHeaderFile( filename ):
        basename = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 0 ]
        for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:
            replacement_file = basename + extension
            if os.path.exists( replacement_file ):
                compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( replacement_file )
                if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:
                    return compilation_info
        return None
    return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )


def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    if not compilation_info:
      return None

    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
      compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
      compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )

    # NOTE: This is just for YouCompleteMe; it's highly likely that your project
    # does NOT need to remove the stdlib flag. DO NOT USE THIS IN YOUR
    # ycm_extra_conf IF YOU'RE NOT 100% SURE YOU NEED IT.
    try:
      final_flags.remove( '-stdlib=libc++' )
    except ValueError:
      pass
  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

Comment: Where's your `.ycm_extra_conf.py` located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` in the root of your project. There is a typo in `MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute`. The if statement directly after the for loop needs to be indented another level since the if statement breaks out of the outer loop instead of the inner loop.

So change

```
for path_flag in path_flags:
  if flag == path_flag:
    make_next_absolute = True
    break

if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
    path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
    new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
    break
```

To

```
for path_flag in path_flags:
  if flag == path_flag:
    make_next_absolute = True
    break

  if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
    path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
    new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
    break
```

The final `.ycm_extra_conf.py` should look like this.

```
# This file is NOT licensed under the GPLv3, which is the license for the rest
# of YouCompleteMe.
#
# Here's the license text for this file:
#
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
#
# Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
# distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
# binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
# means.
#
# In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors
# of this software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the
# software to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit
# of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and
# successors. We intend this dedication to be an overt act of
# relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this
# software under copyright law.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
# OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
# ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
# OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
# For more information, please refer to <http://unlicense.org/>

import os
import ycm_core

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-DNDEBUG',

# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don't want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c++11'.
'-std=c99',

# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x', 'c',

'-I', '.',

'-I', './src/',

'-I', './include/',

'-I', './ClangCompleter',

'-isystem', '../llvm/include',

'-isystem', '../llvm/tools/clang/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/local/include',

]

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
#
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None

SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm' ]

def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return list( flags )
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def IsHeaderFile( filename ):
  extension = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 1 ]
  return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh' ]


def GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename ):
    # The compilation_commands.json file generated by CMake does not have entries
    # for header files. So we do our best by asking the db for flags for a
    # corresponding source file, if any. If one exists, the flags for that file
    # should be good enough.
    if IsHeaderFile( filename ):
        basename = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 0 ]
        for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:
            replacement_file = basename + extension
            if os.path.exists( replacement_file ):
                compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( replacement_file )
                if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:
                    return compilation_info
        return None
    return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )


def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    if not compilation_info:
      return None

    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
      compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
      compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )

    # NOTE: This is just for YouCompleteMe; it's highly likely that your project
    # does NOT need to remove the stdlib flag. DO NOT USE THIS IN YOUR
    # ycm_extra_conf IF YOU'RE NOT 100% SURE YOU NEED IT.
    try:
      final_flags.remove( '-stdlib=libc++' )
    except ValueError:
      pass
  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

---

Useful debugging commands for YouCompleteMe is `:YcmDebugInfo`. This shows you the compilation flags and you would see that not all the flags are there.