# ycm can't find header situated in another directory

Tags: python, c++, vim, youcompleteme, clangd

I use the youcompleteme plugin for autocompletion in vim. However, it appears i can't make it find header files that are not located in the same directory as my source files.
i have the following architecture :

```
root
├── include
│── src
|.ycm_extra_conf.py
```

my .ycm_extra_conf.py is as follow :

```
import os                                                                                   
import os.path                                                                              
import fnmatch                                                                              
import logging                                                                              
import ycm_core                                                                             
import re                                                                                   
                                                                                            
BASE_FLAGS = [                                                                              
        '-Wall',                                                                            
        '-Wextra',                                                                          
        '-Werror',                                                                          
        '-Wno-long-long',                                                                   
        '-Wno-variadic-macros',                                                             
        '-fexceptions',                                                                     
        '-ferror-limit=10000',                                                              
        '-DNDEBUG',                                                                         
        '-std=c++1z',                                                                       
        '-xc++',                                                                            
        '-I/usr/lib/',                                                                      
        '-I/usr/include/',                                                                  
        '-I include',                                                                       
        '-I src'                                                                            
        ]                                                                                   
                                                                                            
SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [                                                                       
        '.cpp',                                                                             
        '.cxx',                                                                             
        '.cc',                                                                              
        '.c',                                                                               
        '.m',                                                                               
        '.mm'                                                                               
        ]                                                                                   
                                                                                            
SOURCE_DIRECTORIES = [                                                                      
        'src',                                                                              
        'lib'                                                                               
        ]                                                                                   
                                                                                            
HEADER_EXTENSIONS = [                                                                       
        '.h',                                                                               
        '.hxx',                                                                             
        '.hpp',                                                                             
        '.hh'                                                                               
        ]                                                                                   
                                                                                            
HEADER_DIRECTORIES = [                                                                      
        'include'                                                                           
        ]                                                                                   
                                                                                            
BUILD_DIRECTORY = 'build';
                                                                                             
def IsHeaderFile(filename):                                                                 
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]                                               
    return extension in HEADER_EXTENSIONS                                                   
                                                                                            
def GetCompilationInfoForFile(database, filename):                                          
    if IsHeaderFile(filename):                                                              
        basename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]                                            
        for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:                                                 
            # Get info from the source files by replacing the extension.                    
            replacement_file = basename + extension                                         
            if os.path.exists(replacement_file):                                            
                compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile(replacement_file)     
                if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:                                        
                    return compilation_info                                                 
            # If that wasn't successful, try replacing possible header directory with possible source directories.                                                                      
            for header_dir in HEADER_DIRECTORIES:                                           
                for source_dir in SOURCE_DIRECTORIES:                                       
                    src_file = replacement_file.replace(header_dir, source_dir)             
                    if os.path.exists(src_file):                                            
                        compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile(src_file)     
                        if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:                                
                            return compilation_info                                         
        return None                                                                         
    return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile(filename)                                     
                                                                                            
def FindNearest(path, target, build_folder=None):                                           
    candidate = os.path.join(path, target)                                                  
    if(os.path.isfile(candidate) or os.path.isdir(candidate)):                              
        logging.info("Found nearest " + target + " at " + candidate)                        
        return candidate;                                                                   
                                                                                            
    parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(path));                                        
    if(parent == path):                                                                     
        raise RuntimeError("Could not find " + target);                                     
                                                                                            
    if(build_folder):                                                                       
        candidate = os.path.join(parent, build_folder, target)                              
        if(os.path.isfile(candidate) or os.path.isdir(candidate)):                          
            logging.info("Found nearest " + target + " in build folder at " + candidate)    
            return candidate;                                                               
                                                                                            
    return FindNearest(parent, target, build_folder)                                        
                                                                                            
def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(flags, working_directory):                             
    if not working_directory:                                                               
        return list(flags)                                                                  
    new_flags = []                                                                          
    make_next_absolute = False                                                              
    path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]                              
     for flag in flags:                                                                      
        new_flag = flag                                                                     
                                                                                            
        if make_next_absolute:                                                              
            make_next_absolute = False                                                      
            if not flag.startswith('/'):                                                    
                new_flag = os.path.join(working_directory, flag)                            
                                                                                            
        for path_flag in path_flags:                                                        
            if flag == path_flag:                                                           
                make_next_absolute = True                                                   
                break                                                                       
                                                                                            
            if flag.startswith(path_flag):                                                  
                path = flag[ len(path_flag): ]                                              
                new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join(working_directory, path)                
                break                                                                       
                                                                                            
        if new_flag:                                                                        
            new_flags.append(new_flag)                                                      
    return new_flags                                                                        
                                                                                            
                                                                                            
def FlagsForClangComplete(root):                                                            
    try:                                                                                    
        clang_complete_path = FindNearest(root, '.clang_complete')                          
        clang_complete_flags = open(clang_complete_path, 'r').read().splitlines()           
        return clang_complete_flags                                                         
    except:                                                                                 
        return None                                                                         
                                                                                            
def FlagsForInclude(root):                                                                  
    try:                                                                                    
        include_path = FindNearest(root, 'include')                                         
        flags = []                                                                          
        for dirroot, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(include_path):                          
            flags = flags + ["-I" + dirroot]                                                
            for dir_path in dirnames:                                                       
                real_path = os.path.join(dirroot, dir_path)                                 
                flags = flags + ["-I" + real_path]                                          
        return flags                                                                        
    except:                                                                                 
        return None                                                                         
                                                                                            
def FlagsForCompilationDatabase(root, filename):                                            
    try:                                                                                    
        # Last argument of next function is the name of the build folder for                
        # out of source projects                                                            
        compilation_db_path = FindNearest(root, 'compile_commands.json', BUILD_DIRECTORY)   
        compilation_db_dir = os.path.dirname(compilation_db_path)                           
        logging.info("Set compilation database directory to " + compilation_db_dir)         
        compilation_db =  ycm_core.CompilationDatabase(compilation_db_dir)                  
        if not compilation_db:                                                              
            logging.info("Compilation database file found but unable to load")              
            return None                                                                     
        compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile(compilation_db, filename)              
        if not compilation_info:                                                            
            logging.info("No compilation info for " + filename + " in compilation database")
            return None                                                                     
        return MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(                                            
                compilation_info.compiler_flags_,                                           
                compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_)                                     
    except:                                                                                 
        return None                                                                         
                                                                                            
def FlagsForFile(filename):                                                                 
    root = os.path.realpath(filename);                                                      
    compilation_db_flags = FlagsForCompilationDatabase(root, filename)                      
    if compilation_db_flags:                                                                
        final_flags = compilation_db_flags                                                  
    else:                                                                                   
        final_flags = BASE_FLAGS                                                            
        clang_flags = FlagsForClangComplete(root)                                           
        if clang_flags:                                                                     
            final_flags = final_flags + clang_flags                                         
        include_flags = FlagsForInclude(root)                                               
        if include_flags:                                                                   
            final_flags = final_flags + include_flags                                       
    return {                                                                                
            'flags': final_flags,                                                           
            'do_cache': True                                                                
            }
```

It's taken from https://github.com/JDevlieghere/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py and slightly adjusted.

I set the completion engine in my vimrc :

```
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0                                                            
let g:ycm_clangd_binary_path = "/usr/bin/clangd"
```

The ycm debug info :

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...                                                                                                                                                
-- Resolve completions: Up front                                                                                                                                                           
-- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_j3wmcevl.log                                                                                                                                                   
-- Server Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                             
-- Server Python version: 3.8.6                                                                                                                                                            
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: False                                                                                                                                             
-- Clang version: None                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Extra configuration file found and loaded                                                                                                                                               
-- Extra configuration path: /home/thomas/game_engine/.ycm_extra_conf.py                                                                                                                   
-- C-family completer debug information:                                                                                                                                                   
--   Clangd running                                                                                                                                                                        
--   Clangd process ID: 4587                                                                                                                                                               
--   Clangd executable: ['/usr/bin/clangd', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-limit-results=500']                                                                                        
--   Clangd logfiles:                                                                                                                                                                      
--     /tmp/clangd_stderrhqcigpx6.log                                                                                                                                                      
--   Clangd Server State: Initialized                                                                                                                                                      
--   Clangd Project Directory: /home/thomas/game_engine                                                                                                                                    
--   Clangd Settings: {}                                                                                                                                                                   
--   Clangd Compilation Command: False                                                                                                                                                     
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:45861                                                                                                                                               
-- Server process ID: 4528                                                                                                                                                                 
-- Server logfiles:                                                                                                                                                                        
--   /tmp/ycmd_45861_stdout_jlaf_q37.log                                                                                                                                                   
--   /tmp/ycmd_45861_stderr_tbwrmn0_.log
```

In the client log file :

```
2020-11-21 15:56:36,990 - ERROR - HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=45861): Max retries exceeded with url: /ready (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc4842db460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078955/ycm-does-not-find-my-headers), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438211/youcompleteme-header-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246209/youcompleteme-cant-find-local-header-files) questions, as well as ycm documentation but i still can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Does YCM successfully generate a `compile_commands.json` file? Do its contents look reasonable (in particular, does it contain entries for the source files you're editing, and do the entries contain the include flags like `-I src`)?